# Can I call placement-new and the destructor through references?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, placement-new

Can I pass around references to uninitialized memory, take the address, and then call placement-new or call the destructor on the obtained memory-location. In other words, is the following program legal C++ or does it have undefined-behavior:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void ctor (std::string &s)
{
  new (&s) std::string ("Hello, world!");
}

void dtor (std::string &s)
{
  (&s)->std::string::~string ();
}

int main ()
{
  std::string * memory = static_cast<std::string *> (
    operator new (sizeof (std::string) * 10));

  ctor (memory [0]);

  std::cout << memory [0] << '\n';

  dtor (memory [0]);

  operator delete (memory);
}
```

It works, of course, and I tried gcc's undefined behavior sanitizer, which didn't produce any errors. But can anyone confirm/refute based on the standard.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes, that wasn't the intention. Thanks!

Comment: You can use static_cast instead. And it is not necessary to cast the argument for `operator delete`

Comment: @M.M Yeah, that's nicer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The above code double-constructs a string at `[0]` , which is a potential resource leak, and double destroys it, which is undefined behaviour.

`new string[10]` constructs objects in  array.  `delete[]` destroys the objects.  You create a new object on top of another, then destroy it, then destroy it again when you `delete[]`.

Nothing else looks wrong; I mean it uses raw allocation which is bad practice in general, and the code is exception unsafe, etc.

Comment: The question seems to have been edited so that there is no use of `new[]` anymore...

Comment: @Yakk Well, the question is "Can I call placement-new and the destructor through references?". The code just intents to make it as precise as possible. Even without the code, I feel that the question is clear enough. And, yeah, I made an embarrassing mistake in the original code. Oh well. Gladly, I'm not too familiar with writing this kind of code, so mistakes happen. But, maybe you're right, and I should make this a new question; not sure if it's allowed to have a question with the same title, though.

Comment: @Yakk So, I can't add a new question with the same title and I can't delete this question because "others have invested time into it". I find the question title quite appropriate. Do you think I should maybe just replace "through" with "via" and ask the question again?

Comment: @Yakk Asking "how can I call ..." implies that it is somehow possible. The whole point of the question is to ask *whether* it is possible at all. Happy for you to change the code to get rid of any UB not associated with the actual question. But I get it: you just saw a piece of code and went into language-lawyering mode. While this may satisfy your impulse to be right, it is not terribly helpful.

Comment: @Yakk I don't think you have to read my mind; just the title and the first sentence of the question. ;) Saying that I explicitly asked "is the following program fine" without regarding the "In other words" is insincere at best. Do you really think it would be a considerably better question if I replaced the memory allocation and deallocation with hand-wavy comments? Anyway, I now think you simply don't know the answer to the actual question, and that's why you are elusive. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
dtor (memory [0]);

delete [] memory;
```

Is definitely undefined behavior.

The lifetime of the object that was constructed in the line

```
std::string * memory = new std::string [10];
```

ended when you use the placement new operator.

Hence,

```
delete [] memory;
```

is undefined behavior.

**Update**

The updated lines of code

```
dtor (memory [0]);

operator delete (reinterpret_cast<void *> (memory));
```

is well behaved.

The destructor of the object allocated with the placement new operator is called only once.

The memory allocated by the `operator new` call gets deallocated by the `operator delete` call.

Comment: The question seems to have been edited so that there is no use of `delete[]` anymore...

Answer (score 0):

After your edit, there does not seem to be undefined behavior anymore.

*However, there's still danger in your code*:
Your `memory` variable has the type of a pointer to a *constructed* string, even though there is no string behind that pointer after initialization of the pointer. And the pointer is not `nullptr` either. That's dangerous. You are asserting to the compiler that something is a correctly constructed object, which isn't. As such, your compiler won't catch you in the act of using the unconstructed objects erroneously.

I would strongly recommend keeping track of the uninitialized memory with `char*` variables, and only use class typed pointers for objects that are already correctly constructed.

Comment: Thanks! But is is really purely at language-lawyering question, not a question about whether this is code that one should write or not (I know, one shouldn't). So in this respect, I feel that the answer misses the point. Can you explain, why this is not undefined. Can you reference the standard?

Comment: Can you explain "asserting to the compiler" ?

Comment: @M.M With "asserting to the compiler" I simply meant saying: "Listen up, compiler, I know you think this bunch of bytes is just a bunch of bytes, but I, the programmer, your god, tell you that this is really a `std::string` object. So, stop complaining about incompatible types now!" This is, what the cast to `std::string*` does in combination with storing the pointer in a variable with type `std::string*`.